# Maximum number of packets

Tags: c++, algorithm

There are r red balls, g green balls and b blue balls. Also there are infinite number of packets given to you. Each packet must be filled with only 3 balls and should contain balls of at least 2 different colors. Find the maximum number of packets that can be filled?

Here is my approach using Dynamic Programming which is straight forward

```
    map<multiset<int>,int> store;

int packets(int r,int g,int b){
    if (r<0||g<0||b<0){
        return 0;
    }
    if (r==g&&g==b){
        return r;
    }
    if ((r+g==0)||(g+b==0)||(b+r==0)){
        return 0;
    }
    if (r==0&&b==0&&g==0){
        return 0;
    }
    multiset<int> key;
    key.insert(r);key.insert(g);key.insert(b);
    if (store.find(key)!=store.end()){
        return store[key];
    }
    int max_packets = packets(r-2,g-1,b)+1;
    max_packets = max(max_packets,packets(r-2,g-1,b)+1);
    max_packets = max(max_packets,packets(r-1,g-2,b)+1);
    max_packets = max(max_packets,packets(r-2,g,b-1)+1);
    max_packets = max(max_packets,packets(r-1,g,b-2)+1);
    max_packets = max(max_packets,packets(r,g-2,b-1)+1);
    max_packets = max(max_packets,packets(r,g-1,b-2)+1);
    max_packets = max(max_packets,packets(r-1,g-1,b-1)+1);
    store[key] = max_packets;
    return max_packets;
}
```

My solution `may be` logically correct but is surely inefficient for large values of r,g and b. I also identified some patterns for r,g,b vs maximum packets but cannot prove them logically.
Can someone help me with their idea?.
Thank you

Comment: What are constraints for r,g,b?

Comment: @MBo r,g,b each can be upto 10^9

Comment: This may fare better on https://math.stackexchange.com/.  It's a math problem that you are currently solving by "brute force".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume without loss of generality that r ≥ g ≥ b by permuting the
colors. The answer is at most ⌊(r+g+b)/3⌋ because every packet needs 3
balls. The answer is at most g+b because every packet needs a green ball
or a blue ball. It turns out that the answer is equal to the minimum of
these two quantities (so without the assumption,
`min((r+g+b)/3, r+g, r+b, g+b)` assuming truncating division as in C++).

We form b packets with one blue ball and two of whichever of red or
green has more balls remaining, or one of each if they’re tied. After
these packets, let r′ be the number of red balls remaining and g′ be the
number of green balls remaining. If r′ > 2g′ and there are at least
three balls remaining, then we cannot have used any green balls yet, and
we hit our quota of g+b by packing them with two red balls each.
Otherwise, we form packets with either two red balls and one green ball
or one red ball and two green balls so as to leave less than three
balls, which means that we have formed ⌊(r+g+b)/3⌋ packets, as required.

Comment: This is a great answer; would it be fair to summarize the strategy as `Take one ball from the smallest pile, then one ball from the largest pile, then one ball from the current largest pile (breaking ties arbitrarily). Repeat`?

Comment: @kcsquared Yes, see the update.

Comment: not so clear to me, you should probably add a small example with the code

Comment: @IkarusDeveloper The algorithm (such as it is) is now given in the monospace font. It’s
not necessary to implement the case analysis, and I haven’t spelled out
all of the details because they’re messy. An example of the case
analysis won’t prove anything.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat yeah now it is a bit more clear, i removed the down vote

Comment: @IkarusDeveloper I believe you can also prove this strategy more rigorously by using as an invariant the sign of the expression `2(g+b) - r`, where r ≥ g ≥ b. If it's negative, we always achieve exactly `g+b`, while if it's nonnegative we achieve `(r+g+b)/3` packets. The sign of the expression doesn't change unless we have fewer than 3 balls. The case analysis is still messy, but maybe this proof feels more 'mathematical'

Comment: @IkarusDeveloper Ok let me tell you what I understood. If r>=g>=b there is no way can fill more than g+b packets. So, g+b is the upper bound which can be achieved for certain values of r (i.e. for r>=(2b+g)). For other values of r, maximum number of packets will be lesser than g+b. Is that correct?